# Send weekly performance metric(CPU,Memory,I/O,Network) reports for AWS resources(ec2, RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, nagios

I need to send weekly emails to my team for the complete performance metrics dashboard snapshot which includes CPU, Memory, I/O, Network graphs for the production server in AWS EC2,RDS database for the last week.

I prefer to use AWS CloudWatch Custom dashboard. However, i am not able to send automatic emails for Custom Dashboards on weekly basis.

Should i use AWS Cloud Watch or some other monitoring tool to achieve this task.

I have created AWS cloudwatch alerts but will only trigger email, if certain threshold reaches which will not serve my purpose as i need complete dashboard to be emailed to my team which includes CPU, Memory, Network for Web server, RDS..etc etc in the same email.

I created custom dashboard in Cloudwatch which displays graphs for Ec2 and RDS (CPU, Memory, Network..etc). 
Is there a way to send Custom Dashboards in email

Expected Results: Setup a email notification ever week that send complete performance metric dashboard to my team members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no way to take snap and send the metrics in AWS.

This may help you...

If you need AWS CloudWatch console UI snapshot, Create Automation Script and configure it.

Way1:

> 1. Write automation script to get Statistics by using below awscli and get metrics by changing "--metric-name", "--start-time" and "--end-time".
> 2. Include sending mail in the script using this [link](https://linuxhint.com/bash_script_send_email/)
> 3. Configure CRON job and configure the script by running weekly basis.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization \
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-1234567890abcdef0 --statistics Maximum \
--start-time 2016-10-18T23:18:00 --end-time 2016-10-19T23:18:00 --period 360
```

Way 2:

> 1. create UI automation script to take snap using Selenium driver
>
> Use this [link](https://www.edureka.co/community/2137/automate-gmail-login-process-using-selenium-webdriver-java) for Console login and this [link](https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html) for Taking
>   screenshot.
>
> 2. Configure UI automation script in JOB1 and enable "Poll SCM" for daily run basis.
> 3. Create Jenkins JOB2 and enable "Poll SCM" for Weekly basis and add automation script as downstream project

Comment: Thanks. I did not mean snapshot, i did not present it properly. I want to send custom dashboard in CloudWatch to be emailed on weekly basis to my team members. Is that possible.

Comment: u mean link of AWS CloudWatch custom dashboard ?

Comment: Thanks. I want send the custom dashboard to my team on email. They dont have access to AWS.  How do you trigger email from AWS to send the link for custom dashboard?.

Comment: I ran Option 1 (way 1), It gets only CPU in non graphical format. I need CPU, Memory, I/O, Network for multiple Ec2 machines and RDS in graphical chart format in one page. I dont mind running a jenkins jobs as cron job and sending email but the Way 1 is not helping much. Way 2, creating selenium driver and writing java code and login to AWS and taking a snapshot will not work either for me. Any more suggestions. I need to provide graphical metrics similar to custom dashboard from cloudwatch that i can share with my team in email. Is there any other alternative. thanks.